# How to convert ARC project to Non-ARC?

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

As per my knowledge, I know that we use `-fno-objc-arc` flag to disable ARC for files that NOT support ARC in an ARC project.

And also we can use `-fobjc-arc` flag to enable ARC for files support ARC in a Non-ARC project.

> But if I want to convert my ARC project(not particular file) to Non-ARC project, then how should I go ahead for the same?

Anyone please brief me about the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to insert manual memory management method calls in the appropriate places. In general, every `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy` and `mutableCopy` call shall be balanced by a `release` or an `autorelease` (the latter is mainly used in the case of return values), so, for example, the following ARC-enabled code:

```
MyClass *myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myObj doStuff];

OtherClass *otherObj = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
return otherObj;
```

should be something like this under MRC:

```
MyClass *myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myObj doStuff];
[myObj release];

OtherClass *otherObj = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
return [otherObj autorelease];
```

More about memory management in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think they are asking about changing the project settings from ARC enabled to ARC disabled, not about converting a specific file.

Comment: @JackHumphries Thanks, I see - but that indeed assumes a specific IDE (Xcode) in this case, and that is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 should i do this in every files of project? is not there any common way to do in single step?

Comment: @SunilTarge If your IDE (for example Xcode) supports this kind of conversion, then you don't have to do it. If, for  example, you use a command-line only toolchain with no ARC-aware IDE (and text/code editor), then you have to do this manually.

Answer (score 20):

you need to follow this step

1. go to your project targets - search - Objective-C Automatic
   Reference Counter
2. Set `NO` from YES

Enjoy Progaramming!

Comment: yes & it is the shortest way to convert ARC  into NON-ARC as questioner demanded for the same that is "if I want to convert my ARC project(not particular file) to Non-ARC project, then how should I go ahead for the same?"

Answer (score 1):

[image]

very simple way edit -> covert ->to Objective-C ARC